# SSRS : How to left align Currency and Right align number in same cell without using 2 different placeholder ? Need same as Excel's Accounting Format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Need same as https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3679-excel-align-dollar-sign-left.html but in SSRS . Need to split a value like $100 as $ on left align and 100 on right align. Without using 2 placeholder inside a rectangle as the report is going to be exported to excel ( rectangle method is creating 2 cells in excel instead of 1 ) and the value should be in a single cell. Also don't need the case statement logic to add spaces based on number value between $ and the number.

Wrote a logic using switch case for adding spaces based on the value length which is working fine as off now .

Comment: Make sure you only change the format property, not the value expression or Excel will treat it as text when you export it.